# Помогите с Html Import

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли сделать через `<link rel="import" href="rec.html">` и javascript так, чтобы на стр показывались блоки из rec.html, в которых checkbox = checked ? И если да, то можете дать пример, пожалуйста?
Пример блока:

```
<a class="a" href="#">
  <img id="recontent" class="recontent" src="#">
  <div class="reslov">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h1 id="reh1">Пастрома</h1>
    <h6 class="reh6">Ингредиенты: ...</h6>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/link-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейшим решением было бы добавить внутрь блока тег/айди:  ... 
И соотв. искать блоки, внутри которых стоит отметка. Ну и потом показывать те, которые нужно показать.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.a')

const checkedBoxes = boxes.filter(box => {
  // вернет false если не найдет отмеченных чекбоксов
  Boolean(box.querySelector('input[name=mycheckboxes]:checked'))
}

checkedBoxes.forEach((box, i, boxes) => box.style.display = true)
```